# How to check which item is visible on screen of recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I want to know the visible item on screen so that if the exoplayer of that item is running I can stop it. Here I have tried many ways to stop already running exoplayer but I've not found any appropriate solution. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this.

Using all these four methods is not giving me visible items of recyclerview. It's only giving me the last item and the first item visible on the screen as their name suggests

```
   rvTips.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
         override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (dy > 0) {
                // Scrolling up
            } else {
                // Scrolling down

            }
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
           // First Method Tried
            firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
            firstCompletelyVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            lastCompletelyVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
          
            for (i in 0 until tipList.size) {
                if (i != firstVisiblePosition
                    && i != lastVisiblePosition
                    && i != firstCompletelyVisiblePosition
                    && i != lastCompletelyVisiblePosition
                    && tipList[i].exoplayer != null
                ) {
                  
                    tipList[i].exoplayer!!.playWhenReady = false
                    tipList[i].exoplayer!!.stop()
                    tipList[i].exoplayer!!.seekTo(0)
                }}

           
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {

            }

            // Second Method Tried
           if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                firstCompletelyVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                lastCompletelyVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

                for (i in 0 until tipList.size) {
                    if ((i < firstVisiblePosition || i > lastVisiblePosition)
                        && tipList[i].exoplayer != null
                    ) {
                        tipList[i].exoplayer!!.playWhenReady = false
                        tipList[i].exoplayer!!.stop()
                        tipList[i].exoplayer!!.seekTo(0)
                    }}

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: you should also check out this video tutorial that could help you out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z44CLCafepA

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop should look like this

```
for (i in 0 until tipList.size) {
    if ((i < firstVisiblePosition || i > lastVisiblePosition) &&
            tipList[i].exoplayer != null) {
                tipList[i].exoplayer!!.playWhenReady = false
                tipList[i].exoplayer!!.stop()
                tipList[i].exoplayer!!.seekTo(0)
    }
}
```

pause all non-visible items - position lower than first visible or higher than last visible - assuming you've collected all `ExoPlayer`s in `tipList` properly

players pausing code should fire only when state change to `AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` (list stopped scrolling, by touch or by fling), so above should be wrapped in some `if` statement

additionaly you can pause player inside adapter in [onViewDetachedFromWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH)) or [onViewRecycled](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onViewRecycled(VH)) method

Comment: Look at the second method tried. It does not work for me.

Comment: show how are you preparing `tipList`, are you shure that `tipList[i].exoplayer` is the same player attached to `View` at `i` position? show some code from adapter

Answer (score 0):

Using the `RecyclerView LayoutManager`, you can find `firstVisibleItemPosition` & `firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` and similarly the last ones.

When an item starts playing the video (assuming you've written the implementation in `ViewHolder` class), you can find the playing item position by `getAdapterPosition` in there. Use a global variable to maintain this `currentlyPlaying` item position (probably in your fragment/activity class from where you are setting the adapter), you can send the position to view class through an interface listener.

Now whenever you scroll, you can check whether currently playing item's position is in visible items range. If yes, you can call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(currentlyPlaying, true)` to pause/stop the player. `true` is custom boolean value you can send to your adapter, which can be intercepted inside `OnBindViewHolder` with `payloads` argument, to toggle the playing state of video.